# Установка RUST на 2 диска

Tags: windows, rust

У меня на компе 2 диска. В основном работаю со вторым D.
Я установил RUST и не могу использовать cargo.
В CMD пишет, что такой команды нет.

Как правильно установить RUST чтоб работало на двух дисках?

Comment: перейти на второй диск в `cmd` — просто `D:`. По проблеме — что именно прописано в `%PATH%`?

Comment: Используйте полные пути к исполняемым файлам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для настраиваемой установки **Rust**'a нужно предварительно поработать с переменными окружения. Для этого сперва добавляем переменные окружения `CARGO_HOME` и `RUSTUP_HOME`.

**Пример**

Например, я создал на диске `X:` подкаталог для установки Rust - `X:\Tools\Rust`, в него собираюсь установить и `rust` и `cargo`. Тогда я создаю такие переменные окружения:

```
CARGO_HOME=X:\Tools\Rust\cargo
RUSTUP_HOME=X:\Tools\Rust\rust
```

Произвожу установку. Установщик, ориентируясь на эти переменные окружения, установит всё необходимое именно туда, куда я указал.

Далее, чтобы мочь запускать `cargo` в любом месте - необходимо добавить отдельные каталоги в переменную `PATH`, например эти каталоги:

```
X:\Tools\Rust\cargo\bin;
X:\Tools\Rust\rust\toolchains\nightly-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\bin;
X:\Tools\Rust\rust\toolchains\nightly-i686-pc-windows-gnu\bin;
```

Первый к инструментарию `cargo`, а последующие к установленным тулчейнам. Какой тулчейн у вас установился изначально - смотрим, соответственно, в каталоге `X:\Tools\Rust\rust\toolchains`.

На вопрос перехода на другой диск из командной строки мне отвечать стыдно. Этой информацией забит весь интернет.